# Find columns whose values are distinct in two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables having same columns.I want to get those columns whose values are distinct in both tables.How Can I achieve this?please help.Iam stuck.

imageid is primary key in both tables.Its not necessary that imageids present in first table should be present
on second table.

First table:

```
imageid  name         id
1        priya        001
2        neha         002
3        divya        003
4        santo        004
```

Second table:

```
imageid  name         id
1        priy         001
2        neha         003
4        santo        004
```

Result

```
imageid firstdata  seconddata  columnname
1        priy         priya     name
2        002          003        id
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Feedback: please respond to (a) comments requesting clarification, and (b) answers received. Remember that every time someone helps you, a volunteer has taken their own time to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have no duplicates, then you can do this with a basic `inner join` with `union all`:

```
select t1.imageid, t1.name as firstdata, t2.name as seconddata, 'name' as colname
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.imageid = t2.imageid
where t1.name <> t2.name
union all
select t1.imageid, t1.id as firstdata, t2.id as seconddata, 'id'
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.imageid = t2.imageid
where t1.id <> t2.id;
```

Depending on types and on the database, you might need to cast the ids to a string.

Comment: if I dont have to use union,how can this be achieved??

Answer (score 2):

I found the following method on AskTom.com years ago and have kept it as a code template ever since. I find it's reasonably fast and I use it frequently.

```
SELECT COUNT(src1) AS in_first_table, COUNT(src2) AS in_second_table, imageid, name, id
  FROM (SELECT imageid, name, id, 
               1 AS src1, 
               to_number(NULL) AS src2
          FROM first_table
        UNION ALL
        SELECT imageid, name, id, 
               to_number(NULL) AS src1, 
               2 AS src2 
          FROM second_table
       )
 GROUP BY imageid, name, id
HAVING COUNT(src1) <> COUNT(src2)
ORDER BY 3, 1 DESC;
```

The first two columns (counts) indicate how many records found in that table, which can identify rows where the tables have multiple matching records.

I've also used this to compare very complex queries by putting them in a WITH clause, so the main query is easier to read.

For example:

```
WITH first_t AS
 (SELECT imageid, NAME, id
    FROM first_table),
second_t AS
 (SELECT imageid, NAME, id
    FROM second_table)
SELECT COUNT(src1) AS in_first_table,
       COUNT(src2) AS in_second_table,
       imageid, NAME, id
  FROM (SELECT first_t.*,
               1 AS src1,
               to_number(NULL) AS src2
          FROM first_t
        UNION ALL
        SELECT second_t.*,
               to_number(NULL) AS src1,
               2 AS src2
          FROM second_t)
 GROUP BY imageid,
          NAME,
          id
HAVING COUNT (src1) <> COUNT (src2)
```

Answer (score 1):

UNION will return unique records on the result. If you specify ALL (UNION ALL) will keep duplicates on the result set.

```
SELECT column1 column2 FROM first_table
UNION
SELECT column1 column2 FROM second_table
```